# Proof of QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

> Prove that any $n \times n$ matric over $\mathbb{C}$ can be written as $A = QR$ where $Q$ is unitariy and $R$ is upper-triangular.

I believe I understand the proof when $A$ is invertible and all of the columns are linearly independent, hence nonzero, and have non-negative lengths. I can use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to create an orthonormal basis, the columns of which are $Q$, and then the columns of the matrix $R$ contain the coefficients of the orthonormal basis relative to the old basis. I'm only having trouble generalizing. Though I can solve the $3 \times 3$ case, for example, I do not know how to prove I can do this for the $n \times n$ case. Is induction the way to go? The other problem is generalizing to the case where $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: doing this with Householder matrices simplifies the matter quite a bit.  However if you want to do with singular matrices and QR factorization via Gram-Schmidt then see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892495/construction-of-qr-decomposition-for-a-singular-matrix/

Answer (score 1):

Let A = [$a_1,a_2,...,a_n$] be the given matrix. Since the rank of A is n, A's column vectors form a basis of the vector space.
Applying the Gram - Schmidt process on the column vectors of A, we can obtain an orthonormal basis, say $q_1,q_2,...,q_n$. 
Observation:
$q_1 = \frac{a_1}{\| a_1 \|}$
$q_2 =  \frac{a_2 - \frac{\langle a_2, q_1 \rangle}{\langle q_1, q_1 \rangle}q_1}{\| a_2 - \frac{\langle a_2, q_1 \rangle}{\langle q_1, q_1 \rangle}q_1 \|}$

.

.

.
Let us now try to write one of our old basis vectors, say $a_2$ in terms of new basis vectors $q_1,q_2,..,q_n$. We get,
$a_2$ = $\| a_2 - \frac{\langle a_2, q_1 \rangle}{\langle q_1, q_1 \rangle}q_1 \|$ $q_2$ + $\frac{\langle a_2, q_1 \rangle}{\langle q_1, q_1 \rangle}q_1$.
Thus for the expansion of $a_k$ only the coefficients of $q_1,q_2,...,q_k$ come out to be significant.
Define
R = [$r_1,r_2,...,r_n$] where $r_i$ is the column vector consisting the coefficents of the basis vectors $q_1,q_2,...,q_n$ in the expansion of $a_i$.
For the reasons said above, R is an `upper triangular matrix`.
With all the sketching done so far, we will now see what is the product QR :
Say the coefficients of $q_1,q_2,...,q_n$ in the expansion of $a_j$ = $(c_1,c_2,...,c_j,0,0,...,0)$.
The $j^{th}$ column of QR is Q$r_j$,i.e.,
[$q_1,q_2,...,q_n$]$(c_1,c_2,...,c_j,0,0,...,0)^T$ = $a_j$

Thus the $j^{th}$ column of QR gives the $j^{th}$ column of A.
Hence,
A = QR.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ the columns
from $A$ and let $q_1, q_2,..,q_n$
the vectors obtained by orthonormalizing them by  Gram-Schmidt.

$$Gen(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=Gen(q_1,q_2,...,q_n)$$

we defined

$$Q=[q_1q_2...q_n]$$
as each  $a_I$ is a linear combination
from $q_1q_2...q_n$ scalars must exist
$r_ij$ such that :

$$a_i=r_{1i}q_1+...+r_{ni}q_{n}=Q (r_{1i},..,r_{ni})^{T} \quad \text{$i=1,2,...,n$}$$

where $r_{ji=0}$ , $j=i+1,...,n$ and  $i=1,2,...,n$, by Gram-Schmidt. then,

$$A=(a_1,...,a_n)=(Q(r_{11},...,0),...,Q(r_1,...,r_{nm}))^T=QR$$

Where $R$ is the matrix whose element $(i, j)$ is $r_{ij}$. The matrices searched are the matrices $Q$ and $R$: $Q$ has its orthonormal columns and $R$ is upper triangular. Also $R$ must be invertible because otherwise $Rx=0$ will have infinite solutions and therefore also   $QRx=Ax=0$ contradicting the fact that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

Comment: I understand the case where the columns are linearly independent. I'm concerned about the case where they're not.